# GAE fetchAsync - what's the point?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

Google encourages us to use fetchAsync instead of other means, saying that since it is asynchronous, it will use less instance hours. However, the method returns a `Future<HTTPResponse>`, and you have to use the `.get()` method to retrieve the actual data. The `.get()` method is blocking, i.e. the execution of your programme will not continue until it returns (or throws an exception).

The question is: what difference does it make? Is it really possible to save the instance time without actually using `Thread`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you can go and do something *else* in between your `fetchAsync` and your `get`.

You can do something like (pseudo-code):

```
future = fetcher.fetchAsync (url)
while not future.isDone():
    doSomethingElse()
current = future.get()
```

Now you could achieve the same end in threaded environments by simply creating a thread to call `fetch` but that means managing your own threads and the interactions between them. In any case, as okrasz points out in a comment, creating new threads is not a possibility in GAE (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#threads)).

If all you want is asynchronicity (is that even a word?) without worrying about all that extra stuff, you can use the `fetchAsync/isDone/get` combination as shown above.

Comment: What if I have nothing to do between the two?

Comment: @Ibolit: then, by all means, just `fetch`. But be aware your thread may not be responsive to outside influences in that case.

Comment: While future is not done -- that is a good point. I somehow never thought of it. Thank you.

Comment: "you could achieve the same end by simply creating a thread" - not true on GAE, since you cannot start new threads there ...

Comment: Note that your hypothetical example code won't work on the dev_appserver, since 'asynchronous' calls aren't actually executed until you call wait(), so it'll just go into an infinite loop. :)